# Finding a polynomial satisfying the equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For
$$
f: x^6+3x^4-4 \\
g: x^5-x^4+5x^3-5x^2+6x-6
$$
how do I find a polynomial $a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]_{(\deg f-\deg \gcd(f,g))}$ so that a polynomial $b \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ exists when $\gcd(f,g)=bf+ag$?

So far I know that $\gcd(f,g)=x^3-x^2+2x-2$ but how can I find a fitting polynomial $a$ to satisfy the equation? I guess I have to find a polynomial $a$ that gets rid of the leftover summands in $g$ for $ag$ so that a fitting $b$ exists that gets rid of the other leftover summands in $f$ with $fg$. But how do I find a fitting polynomial, that multiplied with g, only has summands left that are in $\gcd(f,g)$?

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm works to express the gcd as a combination $bf+ag$ just as in the integer case. Such $b,a$ are not unique, again as in the integer case. Note I don't think one can start with a given $b$ chosen in advance and *then* proceed to find an $a$...

Comment: @coffeemath But which polynomials' gcd am I actually trying to calculate using the Euclidean algorithm? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: But it seems you already have the gcd and are looking for $b,a$ so that $bf+ag=\gcd(f,g).$ So why ask "which polynomial's gcd" when it already seems the answer to that question is just the originally given $f,g$ you have in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
f = hg + r_0
$$
$$
g = q_1r_0 + r_1
$$
$$
r_0 = q_2r_1 + r_2
$$
and so on. In each step, deg $r_i >$ deg $r_{i + 1}$ and deg $g >$ deg $r_0$. (it's the same as you do for the integers.)

Comment: For which polynomials do I apply the Euclidean algorithm here to get their though? I'm a bit lost right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the gcd is $x^3-x^2+2x-2,$ then you can find $b,a$ by putting
$$u=x^3+x^2+2x+2,\ \ v=x^2+3,$$
which are the results of factoring out the gcd from $f,g$ respectively. Then you can just express $1$ in the form $bu+av$ and multiply through by the gcd to get it as "gcd = b(gcd *u) + a*(gcd v)," which given how $u,v$ were defined is the same as $\gcd(f,g)=bf+ag.$

To get $1$ as $bu+av$ takes only two steps, starting with $u-(x+1)v=-x-1$ and then $v+(x-1)(-x-1)=4,$ where we can stop since $4$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x].$ Working backwards then gives $1=bu+av$ where
$$b=\frac{x-1}{4},\ \ a=\frac{2-x^2}{4}.$$